# JDBC query doesn't work when giving NamedParameterJdbcOperation gets date as parameter (in params map)

Tags: java, mysql, date, jdbc, named-parameters

I try to query my Mysql DB using JDBC.

I use the `org.springframework.jdbc.core.namedparam.NamedParameterJdbcOperations`.

The column `DATE_FROM` in `my_table` is defined as `DATE` column (which is also a PK).

A simplified version of a query which **works** looks like this:

```
SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE DATE_FROM >='2015-03-01';
```

But then, I tried to change the the '2015-03-01' to be given as a named parameter. the query looked like this:

```
SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE DATE_FROM >=:fromDate;
```

while I invoked the `NamedParameterJdbcOperations.update()` like this:

```
map.put("fromTime", '2015-03-01');
namedParameterJdbcOperations.update(sql, map);
```

Although everything, to my understanding, remains the same, I get:

```
com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlDataTruncation: Data truncation: Incorrect date value: ''2015-03-01'' for column 'MEASUREMENT_DATE' at row 1.
```

Does someone know why?

Comment: Use a `java.sql.Date` instead.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel, I tried, and it gives the same exception.

Answer (score 0):

Did you realize that you named the placeholder in the SQL "fromDate" and in the map, you named it "fromTime"?